# Accuracy for LSTM stays zero even after using categorical crossentropy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

[image: results]

for some reason my test accuracy is 0.0

below is my full code

```
#seperating the date and count
date = data3['visit_date']
count = data3['visit_count']

labels = pd.get_dummies(date)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(count, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# Split the data into training and testing sets

# Define the LSTM model architecture
embedding_dim = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(100, embedding_dim, input_length=100))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(labels.columns), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the LSTM model
epochs = 100
batch_size = 640
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("LSTM Test Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

my input data is like this:
index / visit_date / visit_count
0 / 2020-07-09 / 12
1 / 2020-07-10 / 8
2 / 2020-07-11 / 14
3 / 2020-07-12 / 12
4 / 2020-07-13 / 6
visit_date is a datetime column while visit_count is int64

I am trying to predict the visit_count based on the visit_date

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming to perform a regression task rather than a classification task, it is recommended to use loss functions such as MSE (Mean Squared Error) instead of categorical_crossentropy. Additionally, softmax is typically utilized for classification tasks due to its output range restriction and should be avoided in this scenario.